# How to include table name in result for wildcard query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm querying from a bunch of tables in bigquery using a [wildcard query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables). I'd like each result row to show which table it's from.

I've tried to include [`_TABLE_SUFFIX`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) in the select, but it won't compile:

```
SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX, *
FROM `foo.bar_*`
WHERE x = ...
```

> Invalid field name "_TABLE_SUFFIX"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use alias as in below example

```
SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX as table_name, *    
FROM `foo.bar_*`
WHERE x = ...
```

You can also use below to preserve full table name

```
SELECT CONCAT('bar_', _TABLE_SUFFIX) as table_name, *    
FROM `foo.bar_*`
WHERE x = ...
```

Note also:  Field names are not allowed to start with the (case-insensitive) prefixes _PARTITION, _TABLE_, _FILE_ and _ROW_TIMESTAMP